# Azure AD Sync Could not Load File

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm having a really weird issue. I'm unable to import the Azure AD Sync module. 
Here's what I've tried:

1. `Import-Module ADSync`
2. `Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync\ADSync.psd1"`

I'm getting the following error:

> Import-module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Azure AD
>   Sync\Bin\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.dll'
>   or  one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. At line:1 char:1
>   + Import-module adsync
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

I'm running under the following premise:

1. Azure AD Connect 1.2.70
2. Powershell 4.0
3. Windows Server 2012R2

The account I'm using is a Domain Admin and should have full permissions. I'm RDPing into the server. I'm also running Powershell as an Administrator. I've checked all installations and frameworks and they are either up to date or not applicable. AD sync is running just fine, I'm just trying to get the powershell CMDlets to work so that I can add them to a script I'm writing.

UPDATE: See below answers for solution. Reinstalling AAD was the solution.

Comment: Try to reinstall azure ad connect?

Comment: I've not had much luck researching elsewhere. That's getting close to being my only option at this point. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else running into this, I found the issue to be when running the (x86) version of powershell is not compatible with the ADSync module. Check your shortcuts that you're using to open powershell. You can use the command

```
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

to check if you're running a 64 bit version of Powershell. If it returns false, ADSync commands won't work.

[example of 32 bit powershell being incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mae1Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Was able to import the module using below command, please try it out.

```
Import-Module –Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync" -Verbose
```

[image]

Additional Documentation Reference for:

- [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594)
- [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-version-history#111300)
- [Automatic Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-automatic-upgrade)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still errors out with the same error message as before. It just starts out with `VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync\ADSync.psd1'.`

Comment: Were you able to download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594 and reinstall and still getting the same error ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had the chance to reinstall yet. I will update this question/answer with my results as soon as I'm able to do so. Hopefully there's another solution, but this is the only option left it seems.

Comment: Update: I was finally able to reinstall AAD and this resolved the issue. I can now run the CMDlets.